# ValueError: Layer #232 (named "fpn_cells/cell_0/fnode0/add") expects 0 weight(s) , but the saved weights have 1 element(s)

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data

I've been trying to train dataset using

```
python train.py --snapshot efficientdet-d0.h5 --phi 0 --gpu 0 --random-transform --compute-val-loss --freeze-backbone --batch-size 4 --steps 100 coco C:/Users/mustafa/Downloads/deneme.v1-1.coco/datasets/coco
```

And I've seen this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 381, in
main()
File "train.py", line 333, in main
model.load_weights(args.snapshot, by_name=True)
File "C:\Users\mustafa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\eng
ine\training.py", line 271, in load_weights
return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name, skip_mismatch)
File "C:\Users\mustafa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\eng
ine\network.py", line 1276, in load_weights
f, self.layers, skip_mismatch=skip_mismatch)
File "C:\Users\mustafa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\sav
ing\hdf5_format.py", line 769, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
str(len(weight_values)) + ' element(s).')
ValueError: Layer #232 (named "fpn_cells/cell_0/fnode0/add") expects 0 weight(s)
, but the saved weights have 1 element(s).
```

I've tried to set

```
weighted_bifpn = False
```

and

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''
```

but they didn't work.
My GPU doesn't support CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include **--weighted-bifpn** option in the command like shown below.

```
python train.py --snapshot efficientdet-d0.h5 --phi 0 --gpu 0 --weighted-bifpn --random-transform --compute-val-loss --freeze-backbone --batch-size 4 --steps 100 coco C:/Users/mustafa/Downloads/deneme.v1-1.coco/datasets/coco
```

The snapshot you are using have propbably been trained with the **weighted-bifpn**. So when you start the trainig it expects this option.